# Unexplained GET errors

Tags: php, apache

I have code that reads the images directory for a user (user 38 below) and returns an array of the file names, skipping the . and .. references.

```
// $dir = 38/images  
    $dirHandle = opendir($dir)$dirHandle = opendir($dir)       
        while (false !== ($fileName = readdir($dirHandle))) {

            if ($fileName == "." || $fileName == "..") 
                    continue;

         -- Put file on array which gets returned to ajax load call at end  -- 
        }
```

This works fine but  it seems to generate the access errors shown below:

[image]

Am I doing something fundamentally wrong?
Thanks

Comment: Your script seems to send `403` headers. Can you find them anywhere in your code?

Comment: Is your rewrite rule working?  Is the script actually running?  Does it have permissions to execute?  Do you have some security extension returning a 403?

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have an `index.php` file in your `38` and `38/images` folders, you are issuing a get over a folder, over which you don't have permissions enough.

Check your script path, and your JS code in order to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I got to the bottom of this.  It happens when a directory of images is being prefetched to the page:

```
while($fileName = readdir($dirHandle))  {
        $filepath = $dir . $fileName;
        echo ("<img class='galleryThumb' src='$filepath' >");
    }
```

The trouble occurs when $fileName is "." or "..".  The `<img class='galleryThumb' src='$filepath' >` echoed down with Ajax then has trouble evaluating a src attribute that's a directory rather than a file. I fixed it by adding a check for "." and ".." :

```
while($fileName = readdir($dirHandle))  {
    if ($fileName == "." || $fileName == "..") {
    continue;
    }
    $filepath = $dir . $fileName;
    echo ("<img class='galleryThumb' src='$filepath' >");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Since you see 403 errors from network panel of **javascript** debugger, it is javascript, who is accesing these paths. The **php** code you posted has almost nothing to do with that.

Comment: Finally nice round amount of reputation =)
Well, this is really incorrect for general case, but a possible source of problem as well.